# Persist user preferences in a cookie on a MVC 4 intranet site using windows authentication

Tags: windows, authentication, cookies, persist, user-preferences

I'm building a new intranet site using Windows Authentication.  The site has a number of user configurable features that I'd like to persist on the client in something like a cookie.  Using cookies with Forms Authentication is a no-brainer, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get them to work when the site has Windows Authentication.  What would be the best way to persist user preferences on the client side?